# Program runs without exception but shows no table names

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have a few DB's in mysql and all of them contain some tables with a few columns. I got the code below from a stack overflow answer. 
The answer is at:
[How can I detect a SQL table's existence in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927807/how-can-i-detect-a-sql-tables-existence-in-java)

The code gives the output-

```
Driver Loaded.
Got Connection.
```

Code-

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DatabaseMetaData;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
DatabaseMetaData md = conn.getMetaData();
ResultSet rs = md.getTables(null, null, "%", null);
while (rs.next()) {
  System.out.println(rs.getString(3));
}  }

  static Connection conn;

  static Statement st;

  static {
try {
  // Step 1: Load the JDBC driver.
  System.out.println("Driver Loaded.");
  // Step 2: Establish the connection to the database.
  String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/";

  conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "cowboy", "123456");
  System.out.println("Got Connection.");

  st = conn.createStatement();
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.err.println("Got an exception! ");
  e.printStackTrace();
  System.exit(0);
}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your Code you only

```
System.out.println("Driver Loaded.");
```

That's not enough. **You have to load the driver first!**

```
 Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
 System.out.println("Driver Loaded.");
```

**I'm surprised that this works**

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "cowboy", "123456");
```

**and that you come to this line of code.**

```
System.out.println("Got Connection.");
```

with the following code, it will go, but you will not get a list of tables

```
static {
    try {
      // Step 1: Load the JDBC driver.
      Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
      System.out.println("Driver Loaded.");
      // Step 2: Establish the connection to the database.
      String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost";

      conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"user","passw");
      System.out.println("Got Connection.");
      ....
      }
}
```

**set the database name correctly**

```
static {
       try {
       // Step 1: Load the JDBC driver.
       Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
       System.out.println("Driver Loaded.");
       // Step 2: Establish the connection to the database.
       String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/myDataBase";
       conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url,"user","passw");
       System.out.println("Got Connection.");
       ....
       }
}
```

and you can see a list of your myDataBase tables.

Comment: I don't see any need for Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
My other codes work well without it too. I tried putting this line. Still no success. Now what ?

Comment: String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/myDataBase"; REPLACE myDataBase with the name of your Database

Comment: What does your question mean ? Program runs without exception but **shows no table names?**

Answer (score 1):

This code is used to display the tables of a specific database, not all tables of all DB. You don't specify any database in your `url` String so there is nothing to display.

If you look carefully at the [link](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.sql/DatabaseMetaDatagetTablesStringcatalogStringschemaPatternStringtableNamePatternStringtypes.htm) used to answer the linked question, you can see `String url = "jdbc:hsqldb:data/tutorial";` So you have to be connected to a database first.

PS : You may have to load the driver if you use driver prior to jdbc4, use : `Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");` and be sure the driver is available in the classpath.

Comment: I never use the Class.forName("xxxx") in my code. I always add the driver jar file to build path and my code works. IS that a good practice ?

Comment: @sweetdreams If you use driver prior to jdbc4 you have to : `Any JDBC 4.0 drivers that are found in your class path are automatically loaded. (However, you must manually load any drivers prior to JDBC 4.0 with the method Class.forName.)` (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/connecting.html)

Comment: @sweetdreams By the way your main problem is that you have to specify the database you want to connect to in the url.

Comment: I am not sure what that means. I don't see any need to specify the database name.

Comment: @sweetdreams Of course you have, how can you affirm you don't? 1) The link you give is about `How can I detect a SQL table's existence in Java?` so it imply you already have selected a database (a database is composed of table). 2) You obviously copy/paste this example : http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/java.sql/DatabaseMetaDatagetTablesStringcatalogStringschemaPatternStringtableNamePatternStringtypes.htm and in the example the connection is on table named "tutorial". Even the comment says `// Step 2: Establish the connection to the database.` But you don not specify any in your code...