# Creating a database table if it does not exist in Java production code and confirming in JUnit

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, junit

I am writing a database program in Java and want to create a table if it does not already exist. I learned about `DatabaseMetaData.getTables()` from [How can I detect a SQL table's existence in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927807/how-can-i-detect-a-sql-tables-existence-in-java) and I am trying to use it:

```
private boolean tableExists() throws SQLException {
    System.out.println("tableExists()");

    DatabaseMetaData dbmd = conn.getMetaData();
    ResultSet rs = dbmd.getTables(null, null, this.getTableName(), null);

    System.out.println("TABLE_NAME: " + rs.getString("TABLE_NAME"));

    return rs.getRow() == 1;
}
```

The problem is that `rs.getRow()` always returns `0`, even after the table has been created. Using `rs.getString("TABLE_NAME")` throws an exception stating that the result set is empty.

One possible solution I thought of is to execute the `CREATE TABLE` statement and catch any exceptions that are thrown. However, I don't like the idea of using exceptions for control flow of my program.

FWIW, I am using HSQLDB. However, I would like write Java code that is independent of the RDMS engine. Is there another way to use `DatabaseMetaData.getTables()` to do what I want? Or is there some other solution to write my `tableExists()` method?

**Added:**

Using the suggestions given here, I found a solution that seems to work in my production code:

```
private void createTable() throws SQLException {
    String sqlCreate = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + this.getTableName()
            + "  (brand           VARCHAR(10),"
            + "   year            INTEGER,"
            + "   number          INTEGER,"
            + "   value           INTEGER,"
            + "   card_count           INTEGER,"
            + "   player_name     VARCHAR(50),"
            + "   player_position VARCHAR(20))";

    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    stmt.execute(sqlCreate);
}
```

Now I am also writing a JUnit test to assert that the table does indeed get created:

```
public void testConstructor() throws Exception {
    try (BaseballCardJDBCIO bcdb = new BaseballCardJDBCIO(this.url)) {
        String query = "SELECT count(*) FROM information_schema.system_tables WHERE table_name = '" + bcdb.getTableName() + "'";
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(this.url);
        Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);
        Assert.assertTrue(rs.next());
        Assert.assertEquals(1, rs.getInt(1));
        Assert.assertFalse(rs.next());
    }
}
```

This test fails on the `assertEquals()` with the following message:

```
FAILED: expected: <1> but was: <0>
```

Comment: Hi, why not just use the SQLs CREATE TABLE name IF NOT EXISTS (...) ? Its much easier, and if the table already exists, it leaves it in

Comment: @bali182 Thanks for the suggestion. The correct syntax is `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS <name> (<columns>)`. Now I am also writing a JUnit test. If you have time, some help would be great!

Comment: I bet you don't have read rights on `information_schema` schema (or it doesn't exist)

Comment: @AlonsoDominguez I will look into that when I have some more time tomorrow.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution I found seems to work:

```
private void createTable() throws SQLException {
    String sqlCreate = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + this.getTableName()
            + "  (brand           VARCHAR(10),"
            + "   year            INTEGER,"
            + "   number          INTEGER,"
            + "   value           INTEGER,"
            + "   card_count           INTEGER,"
            + "   player_name     VARCHAR(50),"
            + "   player_position VARCHAR(20))";

    Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
    stmt.execute(sqlCreate);
}
```

I had to place the `IF NOT EXISTS` in the correct location in my SQL statement.

Answer (score 3):

From the [`ResultSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html) definition at Java docs:

> A ResultSet object maintains a cursor pointing to its current row of
>   data. Initially the cursor is positioned before the first row. The
>   next method moves the cursor to the next row, and because it returns
>   false when there are no more rows in the ResultSet object, it can be
>   used in a while loop to iterate through the result set.

So, you must always call the `next()` method otherwise `getRow()` will always return zero as the cursor is positioned before the first row.

Comment: Hmm...my ResultSet is empty ;-(

Answer (score 1):

There is build in mysql functionality for what you seek: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html

In short: Just append `IF NOT EXISTS` at the end of your table creation query.

Edit: 
There is no general way of doing this. Most databases have an information_scheme table though, a query to determine the information could look like this:

`SELECT  count(*)
FROM information_schema.system_tables
WHERE table_schem = 'public' AND table_name = 'user';`

This works with sqlite, mysql, msql, mariadb and postgres + probably a lot of others.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I need my code to be independent of any specific database engine.

Comment: OHHHH! I don't need RDBM independent code...I just need different subclasses for each database engine...grrrr

Comment: In fact, that might be best since there may be slight differences in the `CREATE TABLE` syntax anyway...

Comment: Your original suggestion to use `IF NOT EXISTS` seems to work. The correct syntax is `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS <name> (<columns>)`.

Comment: Hey, I tried using your select statement and it's returning 0. I'm using HSQLDB.

Answer (score -2):

I don't know if this will necessarily help towards your goals, but when I ran into this problem using Python and MySQL, I just added a "Drop Table" statement before each "Create Table" statement, such that just running the script automatically deletes the existing table, and then rebuilds each table. That may not work for your needs, but it's one solution that I found successful for my similar problem.

Comment: The _main_ (very large) problem with this is that if the table is being used chances are it has data in it. Dropping the table isn't the best solution then.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately this won't work because eventually the table will have data in it that I don't want to get rid of. I just need to create the table the first time the program runs...maybe some kind of flag would be just as good...hmm...