# Create a table in java which is not already exist

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, create-table

I want to create a table which is not already exist in jdbc database. If it exists it should ignore the create statement and execute next steps.

Comment: in postgreSql, you can specify `CREATE IF NOT EXISTS`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11909324/creating-a-database-table-if-it-does-not-exist-in-java-production-code-and-confi refer to the link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use JDBC to create the table at the time of initialization of the application.

At the time of next start, the same statement will throw the sql exception if the table already exists and you can mark a print as table already exists so you no need to worry about that.

There are ways to check before create but then you need database specific queries and again it will be extra overhead.

This technique is the database independent.

Answer (score 0):

use this query:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS <some thing else>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Something`
```