# how to select value from table only if table exist

Tags: java, sql, oracle

I am using jdbc to execute some sql queries. I have the following sql

```
sql="select distinct name, value  from myTable1  union select distinct name, value from myTable2";
```

Problem: sometimes one of these tables doesn't exist and I get java error.

> Error message:  ORA-00942:table or view doesn't exist.

How to adjust the query to run table only if it exists.

Comment: You have to do in the other order. First check if the table exists, then create the query that includes the table if existing.

Comment: Since it's only a select, why do you even care? If he doesn't find the table, I guess an exception is thrown which you can read. But simply catch the exception and return null? I really don't get why you bother here.

Comment: First check if the table exists, these question was already asked a lot of times. [How can I detect a SQL table's existence in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927807/how-can-i-detect-a-sql-tables-existence-in-java)

Comment: @maio290: i wouldnt like the select to break up only because one of the table is missing. It should get values from existing tables

Comment: You can do either that, or you can add Exception/Error handling.

Comment: Even if the two tables are found your query will fail because `UNION` should have same number/datatype of columns selected from both tables.

Comment: @KaushikNayak - good spot!

Comment: You can check in USER_TABLES if the tables exists prior to your SQL statement

Comment: I agree with maio209: why not just catch the error and go on. You need to add error handling (i.e.: a `catch` block) when running the query anyway, so there is no additional overhead for that (but there is for checking if the table is present - which will be done by Oracle **again** once you run the query).